# new homelab server: internal/external network is unreachable

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to setup a homelab on an HP Proliant ML10 that I've installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 on. I'm trying to get hooked up to the internet and my local network. I've installed net-tools via USB and configured my /etc/network/interfaces configured as follows

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.1.120
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

got my Google Fiber box hooked up to the 2nd network port and `ip a` outputs the following

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:4b:5b:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:4b:5b:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.121/32 scop global eno2
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2605:a601:af17:2a00:3ea8:2aff:fe4b:5bcd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
        valid_lft 3595sec preferred_lft 3595sec
    inet6 fe80::3ea8:2aff:fe4b:5bcd/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[Google Fiber console seems to see the wired device but doesn't recognize the ipv4 address I assigned eno2.][1]
I'm unable to ping anything, dns entries or ip addresses, both on local network and on the internet. I've been combing through these forums, reddit and other places but I feel like I've been reading in circles and would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WQ7n.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with net-tools, but Ubuntu uses netplan for network configuration. The default configuration file is: `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` [Netplan.io](https://netplan.io/) has documentation and examples. I reckon setting up your network any other way is "unsupported" on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is amazing @ArturMeinild. Worked like a charm putting the config in netplan. Thank you for this.

Comment: @ArturMeinild especially after the OP has confirmed that this answers the question, the best would be to publish this as an answer... otherwise the question shows up as unanswered for future users.  Furthurmore, doing so will allow for democratic voting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration file is:

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

[Netplan.io](https://netplan.io) has documentation and examples. I reckon setting up your network any other way is "unsupported" on Ubuntu.